# How to count row numbers until a value is found and dynamically the count gets changed whenever the value occurs

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know in vba how to count the row until a particular text "Y" is reached.

For example

[image: Sample Data]

[image: Output]
I want to capture the value of the row count and use it in the for loop

For example,

```
For x = x-1 to ctrow
   Debug.print ctrow
```

In the above for loop the value of ctrow should dynamically change to next row count for "Y" value once it reaches the first "Y" value. There is a "Date" field associated with the "Sample data". Once the value "Y" is matched, the date value of the "Date' field will get copied to a different workbook against same "ID" value.

It seems complicated to me. Also i found out other solution but none is working.
Also, if I need to tweak the `for loop` kindly let me know as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It may be easier to explain what you are trying to do with that information.  What is the final output your want?

Comment: Ok. I will put the final output. Thanks

Comment: You can use a pivot table with a filter to remove the `N`

Comment: You should be able to use a `For loop`, with an `If/Then` statement and use `Index/match` to copy the date into the other workbook. I suggest your try to accomplish a macro and then ask for help when you run into a problem.

Comment: I don't think so pivot table will solve the problem

Comment: I did try to do for loop and if else statement. It seems like it is not solving the problem. I definitely tried before I posted the question.

Comment: Where do dates come from?

Comment: In the first worksheet; what column has the "Y"? what column has the "Date"? In the second worksheet; what column has the "ID"? what column needs the "Date"?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub G()
    Dim rng As Range, lr, rngCopy As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    rng.Sort key1:=rng(2), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    lr = Columns("B:B").Find("Y", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Set rngCopy = Range("A1:B" & lr)
    '//Copy results to new sheet
    With Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        .Cells(1).Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, rngCopy.Columns.Count).Value = rngCopy.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will accomplish your full task, you must change the worksheet names, columns, and Offset to meet your specific requirements(not enough information provided). The code will first_find a "Y" value in your "Flag" column in the first worksheet. Second_it will loop through each cell in the second worksheet and compare the "ID" in the first worksheet to find a match in the second worksheet. Third_If it finds a match then it uses Offset to select the cell where you want to paste the date from the first worksheet. Then continue looping until the end. If you have problems changing the worksheet, columns, or cells references, please ask.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim lRow2 As Long
    lRow2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng1 = ws1.Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, Columns("A:A").Column).End(xlUp))
Dim cel As Range

For Each cel In Rng1
    If cel.Value = "Y" Then
        For j = 2 To lRow2
            If cel.Offset(, -1).Value = ws2.Range("A" & j).Value Then
                ws2.Range("A" & j).Offset(, 3).Value = cel.Offset(, 4).Value
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next cel
```